# Using a swap function to swap the address in pointers of a 2D-array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, 2d, swap

For an assignment I need to make a sorting algorithm for n amount of vector arrays. The assignment specifically tells me to not swap the value of what the pointers are pointing to, but the address that is stored in those pointers. The result will then be printed using those pointers.

My problem is that I can't seem to accomplish the swapping of the addresses that the pointers contain. I have searched SO for related questions but they almost all change the values of where the pointers are referring to.

So far I have this:

Swap function

```
void swap(double **p, double **q, int i, int j){

double* tmp;

tmp = &p;
*p= &q;
*q = tmp;
printf("\tSwapped [%d][%d] and [%d][%d]\n", i,j, (i-1), j);}
```

And my main function

```
int main (void){
int dim, num, *tmp;
int i, j, a;
double **w;
scanf("%d %d", &dim, &num);        /* read the dimension and amount of array*/                                                                  

w = calloc(num, sizeof(double *)); /* allocate array of num pointers */
for (i = 0; i<num; i++)
{
    /*allocate space for a dim-dimensional vector */
    w[i] = calloc(dim, sizeof(double));
    /* read the vector */
    for (j = 0; j < dim; j++)
    {
        scanf("%le", &w[i][j]);
    }
}

a = 0;
while (a <= num)
{
    /*sort num times*/
    i = (num -1);
    while(i != 0)
    {
        if ((argument1) > (argument2) )
        {   /*swap each columns of the rows individually*/
            printf("\tSwapping..\n");
            for(j = 0; j<dim; j++)
            {
                swap(&w[i][j], &w[i-1][j], i, j);
            }
        }
        i--;
    }
    a++;
}


for(i=0; i<num; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<dim; j++)
    {
        printf("%e ",w[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
```

}

When i test this program, it does enter the swap function correctly but the printed result is the same as the input (so not swapped). Can anyone help me why this isn't working?

Comment: Are you ignoring warnings in compilation? Those can be very helpful. I recommend compiling with `-Werror` always while writing your own small programs.

Comment: This helped quite a bit. Turned out my swap argument sent a address of an address (warning was "assignment from incompatible pointer type"). I'm not there yet but you helped me a lot further. Thanks for that!

Comment: Great - exactly. It's good to get good debugging practices now, when you're starting. If you're still stuck you can comment again.

Answer (score 1):

The swap function can look like

```
void swap( double **p, double **q )
{
    double *tmp = *p;
    *p = *q;
    *q = tmp;
}
```

As for the code that is used to sort arrays then it is invalid and does not make sense. At least the variables `argument1` and `argument2` are not declared.

Comment: Concerning the arguments, in my original code there are functions that calculate the magnitude of the vectors. I replaced them with argument to make it easier to read. For the swap functions, arent you changing the value of the arraycel the pointer is pointing to? The goal is to change the address the pointer is pointing to (such that no value is changed). I might be looking at it wrong though.

Comment: You were correct the first time. Have the correct code now. Thanks for your help!