# Sorting 2D array according to one column in C programming

Tags: c, arrays

I started coding about 10 weeks ago and I'm currently stuck doing a 2D array assignment :/

The program is supposed to randomly assign numbers into each column, showing the score of exam1, exam2 and the average score of each student, which is simple.

[image]

But, now I'm supposed to sort the 2D array according to their final "Score."

[image]

The professor only taught us how to do a bubble sort with 1D array, but not with 2D array. But, I still tried to improvise somehow.

This is the code I used:

```
/*for(i = 0; i < 29; i++){
    for(j = 29; j > i; j--)
        if(array2[j-1][4] < array2[j][4]){
                t = array2[j-1][4];
                array2[j-1][4] = array2[j][4]; array2[j][4] = t[4];
        }
}*/
```

But, this would only sort the "Score" column and show the grade for each score, however, not sorting the whole row.

[image]

So, I tried to move the whole row into a 1D array and then swap.

```
for(i = 0; i < 29; i++){
    for(j = 29; j > i; j--)
        if(array2[j-1][4] < array2[j][4]){
            for(r = 0; r < 4; r++)
                t[r] = array2[j-1][r];
            for(r = 0; r < 4; r++)
                array2[j-1][r] = array2[j][r];
            for(r = 0; r < 4; r++)
                array2[j][r] = t[r];
        }
}
```

But the code above wouldn't do anything and the array2 will stay the same :/

Any help?

Comment: Showing pictures of text puts you at risk to be downvoted. (Linking pictures of text without showing doubly so, but I fixed that for you.)

Comment: Try for a [mcve] please.

Comment: The code could be simpler with just one loop instead of three but the idea is correct. Have you run it through a debugger and go line by line to see what’s happening when it swaps elements?

Comment: Some of the most likely causes of your problem are rooted outside of the shown code, that is why making an MCVE is so important.

Comment: With this piece of code you swap two elements of the 4th column. At the same time, do the same for the rest columns. temp = array2[j-1][4];
                array2[j-1][4] = array2[j][4]; array2[j][4] = temp;

Comment: Please post images as text. It's impossible for anyone to copy images (?) and use test them against any code.

Answer (score 1):

Solution according to your way:

```
    for(i = 0; i < 29; i++){
         for(j = 29; j > i; j--)
             if(array2[j-1][4] < array2[j][4]){
                 for(r = 0; r < 5; r++)
                     t[r] = array2[j-1][r];
                 for(r = 0; r < 5; r++)
                     array2[j-1][r] = array2[j][r];
                 for(r = 0; r < 5; r++)
                     array2[j][r] = t[r];
              }
    }
```

and this part where I assigned values in array :

```
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i,j;
    int array2[ROW][COLUMN];  //ROW=30, COLUMN=5
    int t[COLUMN];
    int h=0;
    int sum=0;  

    for(i=0; i<ROW;i++) {
         array2[i][0] = (101+i);
         for(j=1; j<4; j++) {
             array2[i][j] = rand()%100+1;   
             sum+=array2[i][j];             
         }
         array2[i][j] = sum/3;      //calculate the score
         sum=0;
    }
```

...

I think, it's necessary to use pointer arrays for this solution as I mention below. When you try to solve this question with static arrays, it's necessary to assign every value(exam1,exam2,exam3,Score,ID) one by one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ROW     30  //Number of students
#define COLUMN  5   //Keep respectively the values of ID, 1.exam , 2.exam, 3.exam, Score

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i,j;
    int sum=0;
    int *temp;  //use it in sorting to swap address of pointers

    // Dynamically allocate a 2D array
    int **student = (int **)malloc(ROW * sizeof(int *)); 
    for (i=0; i<ROW; i++) 
         student[i] = (int *)malloc(COLUMN * sizeof(int));


    for(i=0; i<ROW;i++) {
        student[i][0] = (101+i);
        for(j=1; j<4; j++) {
            student[i][j] = rand()%100+1;   
            sum+=student[i][j];             
        }
        student[i][j] = sum/3;      //calculate the score
        sum=0;
    }

    printf("\nNotes of students according to ID order : \n");
    printf("ID      1.exam      2.exam      3.exam      Score\n");
    printf("---     ------      ------      ------      -----\n");
    for(i=0; i<ROW; i++) {
        printf("%d", student[i][0]);
        for(j=1; j<COLUMN; j++) {
            printf("%17d", student[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }



    //SORTING

    for(i=0; i<(ROW-1); i++) {
        for(j=0; j<(ROW-1-i); j++) {
            if(student[j][4]<student[j+1][4]) {
                temp = *(student+j);                
                *(student+j) = *(student+j+1);
                *(student+j+1)= temp;
            }
        }
    }


    puts("\nNotes of students according to Score order : \n");
    printf("ID      1.exam      2.exam      3.exam      Score\n");
    printf("---     ------      ------      ------      -----\n");
    for(i=0; i<ROW; i++) {
        printf("%d", student[i][0]);
        for(j=1; j<COLUMN; j++) {
            printf("%17d", student[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }

}
```

Useful links :

[How to dynamically allocate a 2D array in C?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamically-allocate-2d-array-c/)

[Using a swap function to swap the address in pointers of a 2D-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49476057/using-a-swap-function-to-swap-the-address-in-pointers-of-a-2d-array)

Comment: It is one way of doing this; it is not a necessary way of fixing the code.

Answer (score 1):

In the for loop you are only swapping Score

```
for(i = 0; i < 29; i++){
    for(j = 29; j > i; j--)
        if(array2[j-1][4] < array2[j][4]){
                t = array2[j-1][4];
                array2[j-1][4] = array2[j][4]; array2[j][4] = t[4]; // <-- only swaps score, BTW t[4] looks like a mistake, shouldn't it just be 't' as assigned above?
        }
}
```

which I assume is the "4th" element in the array

[image]

You also need to swap the other elements (0,1,2, and 3 too).

```
for(i = 0; i < 29; i++)
    for(j = 29; j > i; j--)
        if(array2[j-1][4] < array2[j][4]){
                // Swap ID
                t = array2[j-1][0];             
                array2[j-1][0] = array2[j][0]; array2[j][0] = t;

                // Swap Exam 1
                t = array2[j-1][1];             
                array2[j-1][1] = array2[j][1]; array2[j][1] = t;

                // Swap Exam 2
                t = array2[j-1][2];             
                array2[j-1][2] = array2[j][2]; array2[j][2] = t;

                // Swap Exam 3
                t = array2[j-1][3];             
                array2[j-1][3] = array2[j][3]; array2[j][3] = t;                

                // Swap Score
                t = array2[j-1][4];             
                array2[j-1][4] = array2[j][4]; array2[j][4] = t;    

                // Swap Grade ???
        }
```

Or as for loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < 29; i++)
    for(j = 29; j > i; j--) 
        if(array2[j-1][4] < array2[j][4]){
                for ( k = 0; k < 5; k ++ ) // you will need to define 'k'
                {
                // Swap all columns
                t = array2[j-1][k];             
                array2[j-1][k] = array2[j][k]; array2[j][k] = t;
                }
        }
```

Comment: I think you're critiquing the wrong code.  I hadn't noticed that the commented out paragraph only processed the score.  The second sorting code block dinks with columns 0..3 and leaves column 4 in situ, which will confuse the sorting algorithm.  Surely there's a way to use a loop in your swapping code?

Comment: hmm, strange. Well, I was referring to the "This is the code I used: .. but, this would only sort the "Score" column" part. Also Sure, I could use a for loop, but I find the OP needs to know where the mistake is based on the original post, then think about a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your arrays have 5 columns so the subscript 4 is valid, your swapping loops never touch the column with subscript 4.  Change the limit 4 to 5, or the `<` to `<=`.  Or use an appropriately named constant for the limit.

Since the question did not provide an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), I've created some infrastructure, and fixed the swapping code using a single variable to hold intermediate values.  The key point is ensuring all 5 columns are swapped; the code in the question does not.  It would be perfectly feasible to use an intermediate array `double t[NCOLS]` and three loops in the swap as in the original code.  This code doesn't produce grade letters.  It does use enumerations to define the sizes of the arrays, and uses an array of size 9 rather than 29 or 30.  This cuts down on the amount of output to be displayed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

enum { NUM_STUDENTS = 9 };
enum { NCOLS = 5 };

static void dump_array(const char *tag, int nrows, double data[nrows][NCOLS]);
static void init_array(int nrows, double data[nrows][NCOLS]);

int main(void)
{
    double array[NUM_STUDENTS][NCOLS];

    srand(time(0));
    init_array(NUM_STUDENTS, array);
    dump_array("Before", NUM_STUDENTS, array);

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STUDENTS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = NUM_STUDENTS; j > i; j--)
        {
            if (array[j - 1][4] < array[j][4])
            {
                for (int r = 0; r < NCOLS; r++)
                {
                    double t = array[j - 1][r];
                    array[j - 1][r] = array[j][r];
                    array[j][r] = t;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    dump_array("After", NUM_STUDENTS, array);

    return 0;
}

static void init_array(int nrows, double data[nrows][NCOLS])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
    {
        data[i][0] = 100 + i;
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int j = 1; j < NCOLS - 1; j++)
        {
            data[i][j] = rand() % 60 + 41;
            sum += data[i][j];
        }
        data[i][NCOLS - 1] = sum / 3;
    }
}

static void dump_array(const char *tag, int nrows, double data[nrows][NCOLS])
{
    printf("%s (%d rows):\n", tag, nrows);
    printf("%3s    %5s    %5s    %5s    %5s\n",
           "ID", "Exam1", "Exam2", "Exam3", "Score");
    for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
    {
        printf("%3.0f    %5.0f    %5.0f    %5.0f    %5.1f\n",
               data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2], data[i][3], data[i][4]);
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
Before (9 rows):
 ID    Exam1    Exam2    Exam3    Score
100       65       95       75     78.3
101       46       56       45     49.0
102       96       61       85     80.7
103       84       95       97     92.0
104       42       80       95     72.3
105       68       47      100     71.7
106       67       47       59     57.7
107       63       90       50     67.7
108       80       48       49     59.0
After (9 rows):
 ID    Exam1    Exam2    Exam3    Score
103       84       95       97     92.0
102       96       61       85     80.7
100       65       95       75     78.3
104       42       80       95     72.3
105       68       47      100     71.7
107       63       90       50     67.7
108       80       48       49     59.0
106       67       47       59     57.7
101       46       56       45     49.0
```